# How to correctly link qt dialogs?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt-creator, qdialog

I need to bind the dialogs so that the "first_dialog" window opens from the mainwindow with two buttons "ok" and "close". Clicking on "close" simply closes the window. Clicking on "ok" should open "second_dialog" also with two buttons "ok" and "close". Clicking on "close" will close the "second_dialog". And if you click on "ok", then "second_dialog" and "first_dialog" will be closed, but the mainwindow slot should be called. How to do it correctly, sketched an example. I tried to bind with the destroyed () signal and write my own signals, but the program was catching a segmentation fault.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    first_dialog* a= new first_dialog(this);
    //connect(a,SIGNAL(...),this,SLOT(new_button));
    a->exec();
}
```

```
#include "first_dialog.h"
#include "ui_first_dialog.h"

first_dialog::first_dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::first_dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

first_dialog::~first_dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void first_dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    second_dialog* a =new second_dialog(this);
    //connect(a,SIGNAL(...),this,SLOT(...));
    a->exec();
}

void first_dialog::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    this->close();
}
```

```
#include "second_dialog.h"
#include "ui_second_dialog.h"

second_dialog::second_dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::second_dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

second_dialog::~second_dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void second_dialog::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    this->close();
}

void second_dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    //....
}
```

Comment: if you want help, you need to provide the minimal working example with complete code, not just the snippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could make use of the `accept` and `reject` methods. In your dialogs call those functions when either of the buttons are pressed. And then just make sure you check the return value to know which one was clicked.

```
// MainWindow.cpp
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    first_dialog* a= new first_dialog(this);

    if (a->exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
    {
        // Both dialogs were accepted
    }
    else
    {
        // First dialog was canceled
    }
}

// first_dialog.cpp
void first_dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    second_dialog* a =new second_dialog(this);

    if (a->exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
    {
        // Second dialog was accepted, so accept the first dialog too.
        accept();
    }
    else
    {
        // Second dialog was canceled
    }
}

void first_dialog::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    reject();
}

// second_dialog.cpp
void second_dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    accept();
}

void second_dialog::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    reject();
}
```